# Finding multiple occurrences of a command in the Dashboard source

Tags: regex, rest, regex-group, splunk-query

I've been trying to work with Regex in trying to find multiple occurrences of all the loadjob commands in the dashboard source code and have been struggling with this. Is this feasible?

Already tried knowing that loadjob savedsearch has "| loadjob savedsearch="user:app:jobname"

```
| rex field="source" max_match=0 ".*(?:b: loadjob.*=.*:.*:(?P<jobname>))\|* .*"
```

Source example (this is treated as a single line):

```
<form script="playground_v2.js" stylesheet="playground_v3.css"> 
    <label>1st Line Clone</label> 
<init> 
    <set token="PrioColor">0xfecb00</set> <set token="Prio1Color">0xe60000</set> 
    <set token="Prio2Color">0xa8b400</set> <set token="Prio3Color">0x9c2aa0</set> 
    <set token="Prio4Color">0xeb9700</set> <set token="Prio5Color">0x00b0ca</set> 
</init> 
    <earliest>0</earliest> </search> 
    <search id="volume2"> 
        <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_Volumes" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | eval conta=if("$report$"=="raised and resolved" AND RaisedSameMonth==0,0,count) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") | stats sum(conta) as conta by _time, Priority 
        </query> 
    </search> 
    <search id="time2"> 
        <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_Times" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
        </query> 
    </search> 
    <search id="sla2"> 
        <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_SLA" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
        </query> 
    </search>
</form>
```

```
<form script="playground_v2.js" stylesheet="playground_v3.css"> <label>1st Line Clone</label> <init>    <set token="PrioColor">0xfecb00</set> <set token="Prio1Color">0xe60000</set> <set token="Prio2Color">0xa8b400</set> <set token="Prio3Color">0x9c2aa0</set> <set token="Prio4Color">0xeb9700</set> <set token="Prio5Color">0x00b0ca</set> </init> <earliest>0</earliest> </search> <search id="volume2"> <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_Volumes" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | eval conta=if("$report$"=="raised and resolved" AND RaisedSameMonth==0,0,count) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") | stats sum(conta) as conta by _time, Priority </query> </search> <search id="time2"> <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_Times" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") </query> </search> <search id="sla2"> <query> | loadjob savedsearch="reporting:fs_reporting:1st_Line_SLA" | search Domain=$history_domain$ | eval month=if("$report$"=="raised",RaisedMonth,ResolvedMonth) | where month&gt;="$start_time$" AND month&lt;="$end_time$" | eval _time=strptime(month."/01 00:00:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") </query> </search> </form>
```

```
| rest /servicesNS/-/-/data/ui/views 
| table Type author title eai:acl.app eai:data 
| eval Type="Dashboards" 
| rename author as Owner title as Name eai:acl.app as AppName eai:data as source search as source
| rex field="source" max_match=0 ".*(?:b: loadjob.*=.*:.*:(?P<jobname>))\|* .*"
```

What I wanted is to get All instances in dashboard source of "loadjob" and get its job name into field

Currently i'm not getting any results with it

Comment: Please provide some sample input text and the output you want from them.

Comment: Just added source for testing in main post

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - to be clear, you DON'T want the search Domain part, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the tag `rest`, but based on your question, you seem to want `loadjob savedsearch="..."` as group 0. So here is some code you can try out:

```
loadjob\s*.*?=(?P<quote>['"]).*?(?P=quote)(?=\s*\|)
```

As seen here at **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5tj8dU/1)**

It also takes care of a scenario where savedsearch is followed by a single quote `'` instead of a double quotation mark `"`

Comment: I get all the instances on regex101 like you've stated but on splunk it's just complaining about the quotes.

I'm trying to apply the rex command:

```
| rex field="source" max_match=0 "loadjob\s*.*?=(?P<quote>['"]).*?(?P=quote)(?=\s*\|)"
```

It just says: Mismatched ']'. definitely complaining about the quotes..

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Robo Mop's suggestion:

```
loadjob\s*.*?=(?<job>(?P<quote>\").*?(?P=quote))(?=\s*\|)
```

This will get the results that i want. Thanks a lot Robo Mop!